# Cannot find last used line of a worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to copy a table from the Template worksheet and paste it 1 line after the last table in all other worksheets (except Sheet1). There is 1 empty line in between each table.

I have checked that the value of LastLine (PI 12 Achievement) is correct.
But, the find method is not able to find the value of LastLine in the worksheet.
The return value of R is Nothing. 
".Cells(RowNr + 2, 1).Paste" is also not working. The debugger always stop at this line.

```
   Dim ColNr As Integer
   Dim RowNr As Integer
   Dim LastLine As String
   Dim WS As Worksheet
   Dim R As Range

   For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    If WS.Name <> "Sheet1" Then
        With WS.UsedRange

        LastLine = ("PI " & ColNr - 2 & " Achievement")

        Set R = .Cells.Find(What:=LastLine, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

        If Not R Is Nothing Then

            RowNr = R.Rows

        End If

        Sheets("Template").Rows("1:14").Copy
        .Cells(RowNr + 2, 1).Paste

        End With

    End If

Next WS
```

Comment: Can you be certain that the test expression for your `do` loop `.Cells(Row, 1).Value = ("PI" & " " & ColNr - 2 & " " & "Achievement")` is validated for a row in the worksheet? You may be better using the Find method, per [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42723569/7531598).

Comment: In `Row=Row+1`, is Row a variable name?  If so, recommend changing to something like `ThisRow` to avoid issues with Excel names.

Comment: This sounds like a typographical error. You should add a `Debug.Print` statement to print each line in your loop to see why your value isn't matching what you're expecting. Maybe you could even add a `If Row = 180 Then Stop` statement to make your life easier with the immediate window. Also wouldn't hurt to make sure that `Option Explicit` is at the top of your module - just in case `ColNr` or something is mistyped.

Comment: And you can shorten your `("PI" & " " & ColNr - 2 & " " & "Achievement")` to `("PI " & ColNr - 2 & " Achievement")` for a slightly better approach on readability. While we're at it, move your `With` statement up a line and change If line to `If .Name <> "Sheet1" Then`... Again, just simple readability. Minor, but in large code it makes it easier to see what you're doing.